# explicit declaration of one-time variable

Tags: javascript

The following code is the skeleton of a function library:

```
var anObject() {

    var private = function() {
        if(typeof oneTimeVar === 'undefined') {
            oneTimeVar = //  code to define oneTimeVar      
        }
    }();

    var public = function() {
       return //value using oneTimeVar
    };

    this.public=public;
}

//instantiated:
var foo = new anObject();
```

The variable *oneTimeVar* should only be determined once per instantiation of *anObject*, and behaves, as intended, as a private member of the object.  However, it's not explicitly declared as a variable, which makes me a little leery.  Is there some other syntax that applies to this situation which should be utilized?

Comment: Since it's not declared, [it is global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), and I doubt that it is behaving as expected.

Comment: What good is that IIFE? It doesn't return anything? Why don't you just use `var private = // code to define oneTimeVar`?

Comment: its global to anObject, but not to the code.  After instantiation, foo.oneTimeVar returns 'undefined.'  If it were global, it would return the calculated value

Comment: Try `window.oneTimeVar`. This is what is meant by global and it's an undesirable thing. I recommend reading the article supplied by @Bergi

Comment: @doctorjay It is global to *everything*. Just do `new anObject(); consle.log(oneTimeVar);`.

Comment: Where did you find this code? Your question sounds like you *know* that it should be declared using `var` - so why don't you just do that?

Comment: I don't think     var private = // code     allows for an actual code block, which is what is required, not a statement.  Let me play with that.

Comment: No, it needs an expression, you're right. But in the end, you could just write all that in the scope of `anObject`, and assign to `private` in the last statement.

Comment: Also, when you said you want one `oneTimeVar` per instantiation of `anObject`, when did you think would the condition `if(typeof oneTimeVar === 'undefined')` ever not be met?

Comment: if I declare it using    var    then    private    never runs.   I'm going to have a look at your article

Comment: @doctorjay Please show us your actual code that you are working with, not an incomplete skeleton that doesn't reproduce the behaviour you claim it does. Is `private` supposed to be a function?

Comment: `function anObject() {
   

        var private = function() {
        if(typeof oneTimeVar === 'undefined') {
           oneTimeVar = 17;  //  replace with time-consuming code
           alert('running the code block');    
        }
    }();

    var public = function() {
       return oneTimeVar*2;
    };

    this.public=public;
}    var foo = new anObject;    //  runs private()
alert(foo.oneTimeVar);     //  returns 'undefined'
x = foo.public();          //  runs public() as expected:  oneTimeVar is in its scope`

Comment: how do I explicitly declare oneTimeVar to emulate this (desired) behavior?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the code in a readable form

Answer (score 0):

Your code [isn't doing what you think it does](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), and there's no point in declaring that `private` variable, using the IIFE or testing for the existence of the value.

Just use

```
function AnObject() {
    // replace with time-consuming code
    alert('running the code block'); 
    var oneTimeVar = 17; // private scope
//  ^^^

    function public() {
        return oneTimeVar*2;
    }
    this.public = public; // making the method public
}

// instantiation:
var foo = new AnObject();
console.log(foo.oneTimeVar); // undefined
console.log(foo.public()); // 34
```

Answer (score 0):

This revision seems to exhibit the desired behavior while avoiding contamination of the global namespace:

```
function my2Obj(hasRun) {

    if(!hasRun) {
        alert('running a potentially time-consuming code block only one time')
        var oneTimeVar = 17;    //  private scope
    };

    var publicFn = function() { 
      return oneTimeVar*3;
    };

    this.publicFn = publicFn;
}

var foo= new my2Obj(0);
x = foo.publicFn(); alert(x);    
//          undefined-                undefined-            error
console.log(window.oneTimeVar + ' ' + foo.oneTimeVar + ' ' +oneTimeVar);
```

The  `hasRun`  flag allows for calculation of  `oneTimeVar` only at instantiation while allowing it to remain in private scope.  If this variable were to be declared at the onset of the function, the code block defining its value would run every time.  In this skeleton code, that variable is a trivial proxy for a calculated array of considerable length requiring nontrivial computation time, required for other methods of the object.  The object itself will be a function library (e.g., `publicFn()`), so instantiation to provide access to its methods will only occur one time.
Thanks for thought-provoking comments and educational reference